# How to calculate QTD values from different columns based on months in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate QTD values from different columns based on months in a pandas dataframe.

Code:

```
data = {'month': ['April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March'],
    'kpi': ['sales', 'sales quantity', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales quantity', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales', 'sales'],
    're': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    're3+9': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 10, 10, 20],
    're6+6': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60],
    're9+3': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 10, 10, 20],
    're_o' : [1, 1, 1, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13]
    }

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
g = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%B').dt.to_period('Q')

if (df['month'].isin(['April', 'May', 'June'])):
        df['Q-Total'] = df.groupby([g,'kpi'])['re'].cumsum()
elif (df['month'].isin(['July', 'August', 'September'])):
        df['Q-Total'] = df.groupby([g, 'kpi'])['re3+9'].cumsum()
elif (df['month'].isin(['October', 'November', 'December'])):
        df['Q-Total'] = df.groupby([g, 'kpi'])['re6+6'].cumsum()
elif (df['month'].isin(['January', 'February', 'March'])):
        df['Q-Total'] = df.groupby([g, 'kpi'])['re9+3'].cumsum()
else:
        print("zero")
```

My required output is given below:

```
       month             kpi   re re3+9 re6+6 re9+3  re_o  Q-Total
0       April           sales   1   10    5     2      1        1
1         May  sales quantity   2   20   10     4      1        2
2        June           sales   3   30   15     6      1        4
3        July           sales   4   40   20     8     11       40
4      August           sales   5   50   25    10     11       90
5   September           sales   6   60   30    12     11      150
6     October           sales   7   70   35    14     12       35
7    November  sales quantity   8   80   40    16     12       40
8    December           sales   9   90   45    20     12       80
9     January           sales  10   10   50    10     13       10
10   February           sales  11   10   55    10     13       20
11      March           sales  12   20   60    20     13       40
```

Here there is four columns named re,re3+9,re6+6,re9+3 for taking the cumulative sum values.I want to calculate cumulative sum based on the below conditions:

1. If the months are April,May and June, cumulative sum will be taken only from column re
2. If the months are July,August and September , cumulative sum will be taken only from re3+9
3. If the months are October,November and December , cumulative sum will be taken only from     re6+6
4. If the months are January,February and March,Cumulative sum will be taken only from re9+3

But I got an error like below , when I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/a/p/s.py", line 54, in <module>
if (df['month'].isin(['April', 'May', 'June'])):
File "/home/a/anaconda3/envs/p/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1527, in __nonzero__
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for new column and then use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
g = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%B').dt.to_period('Q')

m1 = df['month'].isin(['April', 'May', 'June'])
m2 = df['month'].isin(['July', 'August', 'September'])
m3 = df['month'].isin(['October', 'November', 'December'])
m4 = df['month'].isin(['January', 'February', 'March'])


df['Q-Total'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3, m4], 
                          [df['re'], df['re3+9'], df['re6+6'], df['re9+3']], default=0)

df['Q-Total'] = df.groupby([g,'kpi'])['Q-Total'].cumsum()
print (df)
        month             kpi  re  re3+9  re6+6  re9+3  re_o  Q-Total
0       April           sales   1     10      5      2     1        1
1         May  sales quantity   2     20     10      4     1        2
2        June           sales   3     30     15      6     1        4
3        July           sales   4     40     20      8    11       40
4      August           sales   5     50     25     10    11       90
5   September           sales   6     60     30     12    11      150
6     October           sales   7     70     35     14    12       35
7    November  sales quantity   8     80     40     16    12       40
8    December           sales   9     90     45     20    12       80
9     January           sales  10     10     50     10    13       10
10   February           sales  11     10     55     10    13       20
11      March           sales  12     20     60     20    13       40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to map the quarter to your columns, then [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) and [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
quarters = {1: 're9+3', 2: 're', 3: 're3+9', 4: 're6+6'}

col = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%B').dt.quarter.map(quarters)

idx, cols = pd.factorize(col)

df['Q-total'] = (
     pd.Series(df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx],
               index=df.index)
       .groupby([col, df['kpi']]).cumsum()
    )
```

output:

```
        month             kpi  re  re3+9  re6+6  re9+3  re_o  Q-total
0       April           sales   1     10      5      2     1        1
1         May  sales quantity   2     20     10      4     1        2
2        June           sales   3     30     15      6     1        4
3        July           sales   4     40     20      8    11       40
4      August           sales   5     50     25     10    11       90
5   September           sales   6     60     30     12    11      150
6     October           sales   7     70     35     14    12       35
7    November  sales quantity   8     80     40     16    12       40
8    December           sales   9     90     45     20    12       80
9     January           sales  10     10     50     10    13       10
10   February           sales  11     10     55     10    13       20
11      March           sales  12     20     60     20    13       40
```

Comment: have you tried it?